# Hyper-V and Backup Exec 2010

Tags: backup, hyper-v, symantec, backupexec

We are using Backup Exec 2010 R2 with the Hyper-V agent installed on our Hyper-V host. THe backup exec media server is also installed on the Hyper-V host.
When we backup our VMs, BExec backs up the entire VHD file even if the file is not full? We are using fixed disks, so the VM for our file server is 300GB. There is only 100GB of data, but BExec backs the entire full 300GB VHD?

If we were to use the Remote Agent for Windows server, can we just backup the files we choose?
What type of strategy works best for you with Hyper-V?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I like to take a full backup of the VHD and then just use the remote agent for daily backups.
I take monthly full backups of the VHD as well, seems to be working well so far for us.